# Why does the area of an intensity versus wavelength graph in radiation equal to the total power radiated from an object's surface?

Tags: radiation

From my understanding, the integral of a function/graph gives its area and can deduce the dimension/unit of that area. Therefore, shouldn't the area of an intensity vs wavelength graph in radiation be Intensity*Wavelength?

Comment: ["If we want to display information about how much energy is carried at each wavelength, we can make a graph of intensity vs. wavelength. (**What we display is intensity per unit wavelength**, with units watts/m2/nm. )"](https://pages.uoregon.edu/soper/Light/spectrumgraphs.html).

Comment: graph dimensions = [intensity/wavelength] so the dimensions of the area (integral over all wavelengths) = [intensity/wavelength]*[wavelength] = [intensity].

Comment: @user45664 Thanks, then in that case the area should equal to the total intensity instead of total power? Is that correct?

Comment: This might be better if you added an example.

Comment: @Bobby Leung Intensity is power per unit of area.  But this would be the area of the source (or beam or waveform) not the area you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

When graphing intensity against wavelength typically what we are graphing is the [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance). This is the power per unit solid angle per unit projected area per unit wavelength. If we integrate this we get the radiance i.e. the power per unit solid angle per unit projected area.

However depending on exactly what experiment is being done it may well be that the measured quantity already factors in some solid angle and emitter area so it's just a power per unit wavelength. In that case the integral just gives you the total power for whatever geometry is being used in the experiment.